# scanning a string until ":"

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I'm writing a code, in which I want it to scan a name until it reaches ":", but somehow it keeps on scanning the ":".
That's my code:

```
char letter, StudentName[1][40];
int j=0;
scanf("%c", &letter);
while (letter != ":")
{
StudentName[1][j] = letter;
j++;
scanf("%c", &letter);
}
```

also, although the code runs, I get a warning message says: "warning C4047: '!=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [2]"

Comment: Change `StudentName[1][j] = letter;` --> `StudentName[0][j] = letter;` Note: after loop, add `StudentName[0][j] = '\0';`.

Comment: if there is only going to be 1 `StudentName`, then why make it a two dimensional array?

Comment: chux- why should I add '\0'? isn't it added automatically?

Comment: No, in your code, `'\0'` is not automatically nor explicitly added anywhere.  What code do you think did so automatically?  Prefix names with @ in your comments, else the user is not notified as in "@chux" vs. "chux"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it this way, you do not need a variable letter.or if you want to use the variable letter you just need to assign the char ':' to letter and compare it with StudentName value

```
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
for(j=0;j<40;j++){
if(StudentName[i][j]==':')}break;
scanf("%c", &StudentName[i][j]);}
```

Comment: This fails many things: 1) `for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) .. break.` is an unneeded `for` loop and 2) does not let `scanf("%c", &StudentName[i][j]);` to be called.   3) `{if(StudentName[i][j]==':')}` is a syntax error 4) `scanf()` result not tested.

Answer (score 3):

You do a string comparison instead of a char comparison on the while loop condition.

What you essentially asking is ((char *)letter == (char *)"String").

Two things:

One - This isn't how you do string comparison. (See: [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)).

Two - you don't even want to do string comparison, you want to do char comparison, so change the double quote into single quote.

Also, Your string isn't even on the stack, it's on the read only section since it's been allocated on compile time - so no stack / heap allocated pointer will ever be it's equal :).

Also, when you allocate an array with **N** indexes, the maximum index you can access without risking a access violation / segmentation fault error is **N-1**, so in your example, I'd change the line:

```
StudentName[1][j] = letter;
```

to

```
StudentName[0][j] = letter;
```

And also, for the sake of robustness - consider putting an upper bound on the amount of input the user can insert (i.e - another condition to the while loop that place a restriction on no more than sizeof(StudentName) characters.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to declare `StudentName` as char `StudentName[1][40]`. Simply declare the array as:

```
char StudentName[40] = {0};
```

Notice above, the array is also initialized to contain all `zero`'s. This is a good habit to get into. There are a number of reasons why it is good practice to initialize all variables. Here, by initializing to `0` you fill the *character array* (which you will likely use as a *string*) with *nul-terminating* characters, so in the event you fail to explicitly terminate your string, it is done for you by virtue of your initialization.

Next when taking character input, (a character at a time), you will generally want to use `getchar` or `fgetc` to avoid a number of pitfalls inherent in using the `scanf` family of functions. A simple implementation with `getchar is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char StudentName[40] = {0}; /* char array   */
    int letter = 0;             /* int value    */
    size_t idx = 0;             /* array index  */

    printf ("\nEnter StudentName (until ':'): ");   /* always prompt */

    /* read input until ':' (or end-of-line or end-of-input) */
    while ((letter = getchar()) != ':' && letter != '\n' && letter != EOF) {
        StudentName[idx++] = letter;

        if (idx + 1 == 40) break;  /* prevent writing beyond array */
    }

    StudentName[idx] = 0;   /* nul-terminate string */

    printf ("\nYou entered: %s\n\n", StudentName);

    return 0;
}
```

**note:** you want to check for your *sentinel* character `':'`, but you must also check for an *end-of-line* (newline character `'\n'`) and the *end-of-input* (`EOF`, generally `-1`). If you pass a file, or other block of memory to your code, and you fail to check for a newline and `EOF`, if there is no `':'` present in your input, your code will continue reading beyond your input. (until something bad happens to stop it...) Similarly, you need to validate the number of characters you store in your array does not exceed `40 - 1` (to leave room for the `nul-terminating` character). A simple index check or check of the number of characters stored is all that is required.

While you are free to use array indexes to fill your array with characters, this is one (of many) situations where you generally will want to assign a pointer to the beginning of the array and then simply use the pointer to fill your array. It is essentially a 'what fits the circumstance best' issue, meaning neither is more right/wrong than the other, but getting familiar with walking a pointer down a string is fundamental to string/character handling in C. Below is an example using a pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char StudentName[40] = {0}; /* char array   */
    char *p = StudentName;      /* pointer      */
    int c = 0;                  /* int value    */

    printf ("\nEnter StudentName (until ':'): ");   /* always prompt */

    /* read input until ':' (or end-of-line or end-of-input) */
    while ((c = getchar()) != ':' && c != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        *p++ = c;

        if (p - StudentName + 1 == 40) break;  /* prevent writing beyond array */
    }

    *p = 0;   /* nul-terminate string */

    printf ("\nYou entered: %s\n\n", StudentName);

    return 0;
}
```

**Compile**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -o bin/studentname studentname.c
```

(replace the `-O3` optimization with `-g` to generate debugging symbols with `gcc`)

**Example Use**

```
$ ./bin/studentname

Enter StudentName (until ':'): John Q. Smith:Age 21:Weight 180

You entered: John Q. Smith
```

or redirecting input to your program:

```
$ printf "John Q. Smith:Age 21:Weight 180\n" | ./bin/studentname2

Enter StudentName (until ':'):
You entered: John Q. Smith
```

**note:** and this is just a nit, but if you are planning on taking user input, *prompt* the user. Otherwise, the user is left looking at a blinking cursor wondering if the program is hung. Obviously you wouldn't when reading from a file, but when asking for input, *prompt*.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Lots of good ideas!  Minor: `idx + 1 == 40` --> `idx + 1 == sizeof(StudentName)`

Comment: You got me there, but the `40` was intentional to reinforce the `StudentName[40]` correlation, but it would be much more maintainable with `sizeof(StudentName)`. If I had my druthers, we would have had `#define MAXC 40`, `char StudentName[MAXC] = {0};` and `sizeof(StudentName)`... `:)`